# How to apply a normal linear regression in Mahout?

Tags: mahout

I found there's `OnlineLogisticRegression` in Mahout, but nothing about `LinearRegression`, is there any related classes allow me to apply linear regression ?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Apache Mahout doesn't have a routine for `LinearRegression` since it is considered to be a simple problem for even large datasets.

If you still keen on using `LinearRegression` on Hadoop (having large dataset), I highly recommend you to use the [MLib - Apache Spark](http://spark.apache.org/mllib/) library which has support for L1- and L2- regularized Linear Regression that runs on Hadoop extremely efficient and highly scalable.